# How to check which IP addresses a Pod is accessing?

Tags: kubernetes, networking

We are applying Network Policy to our Kubernetes Cluster. Is there an easy way to find out which IP addresses we need to add to our egress?

We have added some successfully, but struggling with some parts.

Specifically, CDN management using Microsoft library:

```
CdnManagementClient.Endpoints.PurgeContent(_cdnConfig.ResourceGroupName, _cdnConfig.ProfileName, _cdnConfig.EndpointName, contentPaths);
```

We already added some IP addresses, but there seem to be no clear documentation on which IP this calls to.

Is there a way to *listen* and find out which IP / hostname the pod is trying to call?

Comment: Investigate you CNI, virtual network or network for this. This is nothing the Kubernetes API can help you with, it is more related to your specific network solution.

Comment: Sounds like you're using Azure AKS, did you check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-network-policies) as a starting point?